# I haven't finished my undegraduate degree but I'm a coauthor in an article. What should I put as my college level?

Tags: publications, mathematics, undergraduate

I finished all my courses at my college as a math undegrad but I don't have my degree, because I haven't submitted my thesis. (It is necesarry to submit the thesis to get the degree.)

At my job, we did a research project, and I'm a coauthor. Everyone else has a master's degree or a PhD, but I don't. For example, my boss finished his courses in a math graduate program and he is writing himself as "John Smith, BMath". How should I write my scholar level?

Comment: Some PhD students who are just short of their dissertation write PhD (ABD) where ABD stands for "all but dissertation". Perhaps that's an option?  Possibly a bit strange for an undergraduate degree.

Comment: The entire title is about one-upmanship and basically devolves into appeal to authority since none of it says anything about the quality of the article.

Answer (score 9):

You haven't formally graduated yet, so you can't claim to have any degree. Whether or not you have published a research paper is irrelevant. Simply write "Ms Perez" or "Valeria Perez". If there is a short bio/contact section in the publication, you can include your current educational status there, e.g., "Valeria Perez, student, XY college, department of mathematics".